# Turtlebot 2 dimensions

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, turtlebot2

I am trying to drive the differential drive kinematics of Turtlebot 2. However, I couldn't find the distance between 2 wheels on the datasheet. I'd appreciate if anyone could provide me this dimension.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that seems like a pretty critical dimension to be missing for a differential drive robot!

Answer (score 1):

The specs are listed here:

https://www.active-robots.com/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2FFile-1434995349.pdf

While they don't directly list the distance between wheels, they do list everything that you need for a kinematics model. I would especially focus on these two numbers:

- Maximum translational velocity: 70 cm/s
- Maximum rotational velocity: 180 deg/s

Comment: It appears that the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

23 cm from center to center. The wheel's width is 2.4 cm.